# Doctrine Autoloader With Threading PHP

Tags: php, multithreading, doctrine

Hello I am new to pthread in php so go easy on me.

I have a class that runs a method in multiple threads in php.

```
 public function run()
{       
    require_once($this->classPath);

    $em = \DoctrineEntityManager::forAxxess1();
    $monthend = new $this->classNameWithNamespace($em);

    $monthend->process();
}
```

However I keep getting errors from the autoloaded classes. The error in the php error log is not informative at all.

Here is my autoloader code.

```
$loader = require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

$doctrineLoader = new DoctrineClassLoader('Entity', SITE_ROOT);
$doctrineLoader->register();
```

The place that it errors out is where I inherit the EntityRepository class.

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
```

Please let me know what extra details I can send you.